# How to find out the location of the device using android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getNetworkOperator?

Tags: java, android

This method returns the numeric name (MCC+MNC) of current registered operator. How can I find out from which state this device is? I'm ready to create a database that stores pairs of values - state. Just tell me where to find the value of which state corresponds.

Comment: You don't.  That's not what they're there for.  Nor are you assured those will have valid values for all networks (for example CDMA did not require an MCC), or that an MCC/MNC combo will map to a particular state.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [Location Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) to accomplish that.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I'm interested in how I can determine the geolocation from the value obtained by this method.

Comment: That’s not possible using that class/method.  Is there a particular reason why you can’t use LocationManager as I suggested?